# How to create a function for mapping a column's value from one file to another

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have two dataframe -

1. [Dataset - 1 containing 5 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9pK5.png)

2. [Dataset - 2 containing 2 columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxWrj.png)

These are the sample dataset. I want to create a function wherein I want to change/map "country" column in Dataset - 1 to COUNTRY_NAME of Dataset - 2. The final dataset should look like this -

[Required output dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOCjA.png)

Since I have no common column in Dataset - 1 and Dataset - 2, I am facing an issue as to how can I map country values. Help !!

```
import pandas as pd

Dataset_2 = pd.read_csv('country_codes.csv')
Dataset_1 = pd.read_csv('Registrants.csv')
reg.dropna(inplace=True)

def findCorrectCountryname (country_name,country_code):
    if country_code:
        return( df.loc[df['COUNTRY_CODE'] == country_code,'COUNTRY_NAME'].iloc[0])
    elif country_name.startswith('United States'):
        return ('United States of America')
    elif country_name.startswith('Korea, South') :
        return('South Korea')   
    elif country_name.startswith('Bahamas, The'):
        return('The Bahamas')
    elif df['COUNTRY_NAME'].str.contains(country_name).any():
        return(country_name)
    else:
        return ("not found {}".format(country_name))




reg['country_corrected'] = reg.apply(lambda row: findCorrectCountryname(row.country,country_code=None) , axis = 1)
reg.to_csv('corrected country names.csv',index=False)
```

How can I make this code more readable??

I have came across a solution, need suggestion:

IF VALUE OF DATASET_1['country'].isin.DATASET_2['COUNTRY_CODE'] then return the value of DATASET_1['country'] else return close match( of the value ) from DATASET_2

I am unable to write the above line in python code. Help

Comment: it looks like you are trying to figure out a "similarity score" that will let you map "country" in dataset 1 to "COUNTRY_NAME" in dataset 2. try looking for something like [Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/Levenshtein/#description)

Comment: @Nullman Levenshtein is just giving me the score (match score/ratio). I want to map values(records from dataset 2 into dataset 1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu Provided with a code, kindly let me know how can I make it more readable?

Comment: Depending on the size of the datasets I might just be inclined to manually create a mapping between the desired columns. It does not seem worth automating. If the datasets are really big and the task can't be done manually then I would create a regex pattern using the first column and create a mapping. Instead of applying a function row by row I would just use pandas replace and the mapping I created to accomplish this task.

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu The dataset is big. I have just provided a sample here. Could you please guide me as to how I can create a regex and match it.

Comment: I was saying I would still create the mapping manually and automate only the assigning part. If you have really dirty data then you can't use simple regex. You'll have to do fuzzy matching

Comment: @alparslanmimaroğlu I have tried fuzzy matching too, but it's applicable only for a series object or a defined variable and not on multiple columns of separate dataframes. And also, the values are not in sequence